# How to make separated validation in WPF Application in Windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I want to make validation in a separated xaml definition with my own custom code in C# to make windows form. I have been [read the resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation#custom) about code like this validation with custom validation

```
 <Window  xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:MyValidators" [...]/>
```

and then this is the xaml definition with custom code

```
  <TextBox x:Name="textAge">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
              <validators:StringRangeValidationRule 
                 MinimumLength="1" 
                 ErrorMessage="Age is required." />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But I want the validation become like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="textAge" Text="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
```

And in separate file I want to define my own validation for example `Validation.xml`

```
<validation:StringrangeValidationRule target="textAge"  MinimumLength="1" errorMessage="Age is required" />
```

How I can accomplish this I have so many textBox with different validation rules. I don't want to mix up the definition of textbox and validation in one place that can make me hard to read the code...

Any help regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the Binding and the validation rule in a keyed style and assign that to text box. Here is an example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SomeNameTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="SomeName">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validators:StringRangeValidationRule 
                                 MinimumLength="1" 
                                 ErrorMessage="SomeName is required." />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Assign this style to the textbox

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource SomeNameTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

I think this should work. However I would suggest you to also look at IDataErrorInfo interface which also provides a way to validate properties.

Comment: But my textbox almost has different validation for each one.. Is there any method that like I described before..

Comment: You can have as many styles defined for TextBox in a XAML resource dictionary and have them assigned to different individual TextBoxes based on the key. For example you can have Style **TextBoxStyle1** targeting **TextBox1** and **TextBoxStyle2** targeting **TextBox2** and so on. If you want to persist with WPF ValidationRule, then define a base style for your TextBox which will include your normal styles for all TextBoxes, and then for individual TextBox styles containing Validation Rule, use the  **BasedOn** attribute of the style like **BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBoxStyle}"**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Enterprise Library Validation application block. You can then specify validation on your object properties via attributes or configuration (in a separate, non-compiled XML file).

Your XAML then looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

There is a [new version of Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn169621.aspx) (version 6) that was released in April this year.

These [hands-on labs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23645) from Microsoft give a good walkthrough of how to get you started (it's for an earlier version but the principles are the same).